# Positive orientation forms is an open set, Orientations of Mantifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

This is in page 381, of John Lee's Introuduction to smooth manifold of his proof of Prop 15.5.

> **Prop 15.5:** If $M$ is given an orientation, then there is a smooth nonvanishing $n$-form on $M$ that is positively oriented at each point.

He claimed the following is true:

> Let $M$ be an oriented $n$- manifold. Then $\wedge^n_+ T^*M $ is open in $\wedge^nT^*M$ where $\wedge^n_+T^*M$ is the subset consisting of positively orineted $n$-covectors at all points of $M$.

Why is it so? I have written  what I think constitute as a proof below. Feel free to criticize.

---

**Proof:**

If $M$ is orietned $n$-manifold. There exists local frame $\sigma$ on a neighborhood $U$, which is positively oriented. This corresponds to a local trivlization, 
$$ \Phi: \pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U \times \Bbb R,  v_p\sigma(p) \mapsto (p,v_p). $$
Where $v_p \in \Bbb R$. Then 
$$ \wedge^n_+T^*M \cap \pi^{-1}(U) = \Phi^{-1}(U \times \Bbb R_{>0}). $$ 
which is an open set. So $\wedge^n_+T^*M$ is union of open sets.

Comment: It's ok for me.

Comment: @Sou, thanks, I have also written a new question recently on interior multipliciation, I wonder if you could give it a look.

Comment: I've added a comment to you question.